# Can't get WCF Duplex ChannelFactory to fault properly

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory, duplex-channel, faulted

Given a valid Binding and EndpointAddress, I have a WCF Duplex ChannelFactory like so:

```
NetTcpBinding svcBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
svcBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
EndpointAddress svcEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp:// + ServiceAddress + "/Service"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(UserPrincipalName));

DuplexChannelFactory dcf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(new InstanceContext(this), svcBinding);
dcf.Opened += OnCommunicationOpened;
dcf.Faulted += OnCommuicationFaulted;
IService svc = dcf.CreateChannel(svcEndpointAddress);

public void OnCommunicationOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something . . .
}

public void OnCommunicationFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something else . . .
}
```

The opened event has no problem firing, but the faulted event does not fire when I close my service. How can I get the Faulted event to fire?

Comment: How you configured svcBinding?

Comment: What do you mean by "configured?"

Comment: What type svcBinding have, what is in fields of svcBinding

Comment: It's a TcpBinding: See my edited code that has definitions of TcpBinding.